# Wikipedia API returns no links for specific articles

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have a query that gets all the links in a Wikipedia article. The problem is that for some pages, it returns no link.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maramures_County) has many links on it.
However, my query:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=Maramures_County&prop=links&plnamespace=0&pllimit=250&format=xml&action=query

Returns only:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <api>
        <query>
            <normalized>
                <n to="Maramures County" from="Maramures_County"/>
            </normalized>
            <pages>
                <page title="Maramures County" ns="0" pageid="3625444">
                    <links>
                        <pl title="Maramureș County" ns="0"/>
                    </links>
            </page>
        </pages>
    </query>
</api>
```

If I run the same query for another article, likes "Moon", I get lots of results.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=Moon&prop=links&plnamespace=0&pllimit=250&format=xml&action=query

Returns

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <api>
        <query-continue>
            <links plcontinue="19331|0|JSTOR"/>
        </query-continue>
        <query>
            <pages>
                <page title="Moon" ns="0" pageid="19331">
                <links>
                    <pl title="3753 Cruithne" ns="0"/>
                    <pl title="51st state" ns="0"/><pl title="Ablation" ns="0"/>

                    [ ... etc, etc  ...]
```

Am I doing something wrong with the API or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the article `Maramures County` is a redirect to `Maramureș County` (notice the comma below s), which means it's technically [an article with a single link to the redirect target](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Maramures_County&redirect=no).

To get the links, you can either use the name of the actual article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=Maramure%C8%99%20County&prop=links&plnamespace=0&pllimit=250&format=xml&action=query

Or you can use the `redirects` parameter:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?titles=Maramures%20County&prop=links&plnamespace=0&pllimit=250&format=xml&action=query&redirects